# Using AWS SecretManager with Fargate: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager

**The scenario**:

We have a K8s cluster on EKS using Fargate nodes. I am storing our credentials/secrets in AWS SecretManager and want our workers deployed on AWS Fargate to access these secrets directly.

**The issue**:

The python code inside the containers throw the following error, as it cannot find any aws credentials):
`botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`

It is quite similar to the issue raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068942/pod-on-fargate-from-eks-does-not-have-access-to-aws-default-credentials/60073089#60073089) and I already went ahead to add a service account as proposed in the answer to that question.

Specifically, I followed the [guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/specify-service-account-role.html).

However, the last step does not return the expected output for me. There is no AWS environment variable being injected into any of the pods.

I also tried following the workshop here:https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/110_irsa/deploy/
but still not getting the expected output.

I will appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe  you are missing the cluster create steps as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/). Specifically:

- Set up the OIDC ID provider (IdP) in AWS.

If you like to inject things into your Pods automatically consider creating a [MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) which basically responds to with `JSONPatch` that K8s applies to whatever object you specify.

[This is](https://medium.com/ovni/writing-a-very-basic-kubernetes-mutating-admission-webhook-398dbbcb63ec) a detailed walkthrough on how to create one.

Comment: Thanks @Rico. I created the cluster already and can confirm it works(installed a sample app on it). The issue is how I can inject the credentials that the pods need to run(or a way to have the pods pull them)

Comment: Added more details, you can create MutatingAdmissionWebhook that injects the annotations in the pod for example. Not that simple but a path to get what you want to be injected into your pods.